# jquery gridview row height sum for all rows up to index n

Tags: jquery, gridview, height

I have a grid view on a page and the row height can vary.  I have some clickable objects that correspond to the index of the rows in my grid view.  So the index of the item clicked would be the row number of my gridview.

Is there any way in jQuery to get the sum of the rows in an asp gridview height up to row n.

So if I clicked index 3 i would get back (rowheight[0] + rowheight[1] + rowheight[2])

The reason i want to know this is so i can scroll the gridview down to the item clicked.  I need to know how many pixels to scroll though.

Thanks Bunches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```
var index = 3;
var totalHeight = 0;
$("#yourGridViewId tr:lt(" + index + ")").each(function() {
    totalHeight += $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is working.  I was wondering if there might be an easier way though.  Is there a way to scroll down to the index i want in a gridview withouth taking all the height measurements?  Sometimes when i scroll down the item is a cut off a little from scroling to much.